# VMWare graphic card

Tags: vmware

Is it possible to use the native graphic card of my pc (Windows 7) when I run my vmware 7? I am trying to run Final Cut Pro X on my guest OS (Lion) but it says the graphic setting doesn't support Final Cut Pro X. Any fix? Thanks.

Comment: Using OS X on non-Apple hardware is against the EULA.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. You have to use a Mac.

Comment: Currently, not. That's because Quartz Extreme/Core Image (QE/CI) drivers are not available for Vmware Workstation. So you can't have proper GPU acceleration running macOS as a guest in Workstation (or Virtualbox I presume).

Answer (score 2):

Try using adobe premier, Sony Vegas, Avid etc on your pc installed on Windows, there are plenty of Windows editing programs that are equally as good if not better than Mac software.

You will get on a lot better than trying to virtualise your video editing, as running a virtual machine takes quite a lot of overhead to start with so you would be far far better off just running the video editing software on your physical pc and turning off the virtual machine.

Unless you have a crazy powerful pc its not going to happen even if the vm did support the graphics card, you have to think that when the vm is running it isn't using all the memory / cpu the system has, because some of that is allocated to running Windows 7 itself, and the VM host software, where as if you run editing software on windows itself you will be getting a hell of a lot more of the pc's memory / cpu allocated to the program as your not having to run Windows 7 AND the VM host software AND the mac OS software AND the video editing software, you only having to run Windows 7 AND the Video Editing software.

Comment: +1 for not trying to kludge your way around a problem and instead using tools made for the job.  If you have Windows you use Windows tools, not hoping and praying that a Mac tool *might* work well enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use the native graphic card of my pc (Windows 7) when I run my vmware 7?

No, this is not currently possible.  'They' are working on this with the [VT-d extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#I.2FO_MMU_virtualization_.28AMD-Vi_and_VT-d.29) to CPUs, but almost no software actually supports this yet. AFAIK, only Vmware ESX has support for this feature, but this is an Enterprise product and would not be useful at all on your desktop.